# Elements in cake php

Tags: cakephp

i am using linux-mint os
i have to put a search form on front-end on my web's home page: 
i have done something like this:

Model for my app:
var/www/project/app/model/search.php

```
    <?php
     class Search extends AppModel {
     var $name = 'Search';

     }
    ?>
```

My controller :
var/www/project/app/controller/searches_controller.php

```
        <?php
         class SearchesController extends AppController {
     var $name = 'Searches';
     var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');
          function search()
          {
            $this->layout = 'default';
            return $searches = $this->Search->find('all');
          }

        }
       ?>
```

After following the above steps i have create an Element to show the form on my home page
My Element :
var/www/project/app/views/element/search.ctp

```
       <?php 
        $searches = $this->requestAction('searches/search');
       ?>
       <?php
          echo $form->create('Search', array('controller'=>'searches',
                               'action' => 'search'));?>
         <select name="search">
         <option>------Select------</option>
         <?php  foreach($searches as $search) { ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $search['Search']['id'];?>">
         <?php echo   $search['Search']['media'];?></option>
        <?php } ?>
        </select>

     <?php echo $form->end('submit'); ?>
```

And i put code in my default.ctp like this :

```
     <?php echo $this->element('search');?>
```

Having done all this, i tried to view my home page but it shows an error message:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function create() on a non-object in
>   /var/www/Emedia/app/views/elements/search.ctp on line 4

Notice (8): Undefined variable: form [APP/views/elements/search.ctp, line 4]

Answer (score 0):

The form should be:

```
//in your element
//remove echo $element->create... and use
echo $form->create('Search', array(
        'id' => 'someform', 
        'url' => array(
            'controller' => 'searches', 
            'action' => 'search')
        )
    ); 
//and form end
echo $form->end('submit'); //not $element->end('submit');
```

Answer (score 0):

there shouldnt be any "return" - why are you doing that?
use "cake bake" if you are not yet familiar with how it works.

anyway, that should help:

```
$searches = $this->Search->find('all');
$this->set(compact('searches'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $form->create('Search', array('controller'=>'searches',
                               'action' => 'search'));?>
```

instead of using :

```
echo $this->Form->create('Search', array('controller'=>'searches',
                               'action' => 'search'));?>
```

it will Resolve :

> Fatal error: Call to a member function create() on a non-object in
>   /var/www/Emedia/app/views/elements/search.ctp on line 4

Comment: It's $this->Form, not $this->FORM and it depends on which version of CakePHP is being used.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CakePHP 2.x then I thinks you cant access FormHelper directly through variable $form

Try:

```
$this->Form->create('Search',array('action'=>'yourAction'));
```